# JTable refreshing from another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have this method:

```
public void refreshTable() {
    Object[][] datax = DB.getData(emailAddress);
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(datax, columnNames);
    table.setModel(model);
}
```

and I call it in another class:

```
private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
EmailManager em = new EmailManager(emailAddress);
    em.refreshTable();
    dispose();
}
```

The table is not refreshing. Both classes contain different GUI's.
I have read other posts where it is said that is not possible to do this, but a professor told me that there is a way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of `EmailManager` you're refreshing isn't the same one that is displayed on the screen, so they have no relationship.

From the look of things, you probably should be using a modal dialog of some kind, when the dialog is closed(and it returns to the caller), you should then refresh the instance of `EmailManager` which is actually on the screen.

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Alternatively, you will need to pass the instance of the `EmailManager` to your other class, but this exposes the class to possible misuse